# Surface area of $y = \ln(x)$ rotated about y-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, rotations

I have to find the surface area formed by rotating $y=\ln(x)$, $1\le x\le e$, about the $y$-axis. I have done the following steps but I am not sure about it. Is there any hint/insight for me on it? Thank you. Here is the link to it:

[image]

Comment: Please do not link to images.  Users here are very busy, they volunteer their time, and really don't much like chasing links,

Comment: My account is new and the site doesn't allow me to post images...

Comment: Joanna, I didn't ask you to upload images.  You should do your best to type in what you want to show us. For new users there are always other users who are eager to edit to an even better representation.  And then, start learning basic mathjax afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Try the change of variables $e^y=z$ and after that another change of variables $z=\sinh(u)$

Comment: why is this related to sinh?

Comment: Recall that $\cosh^{2}(x)-\sinh^{2}(x)=1$.

Comment: should I divide the whole thing by 2 (and multiply a 2 outside of the integral)?

Comment: Which integral do you obtain after the change of variables $z=e^{y}$?

Comment: $z sqrt(1+z^2) dz$

Comment: are you sure there is a $z$ outside the root? $dz=e^{y}dy$

Comment: It is the $e^y$ outside the root. Did I misunderstand change of variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122894/discussion-between-sapotonto-and-joanna-a).